# Tween Animation

Tags: android, android-sdk

Для чего нужны эти значения, при создании анимации alpha, scale, translate, rotate и set ? :
fillBefore — когда установлен в true, то преобразование анимации применяется перед началом анимации;
fillAfter — когда установлен в true, то преобразование применяется после конца анимации;

Answer (score 1):

Set - Набор, он позволяет применить к объекту не одну анимацию, а сразу несколько.
Scale - масштабирование.
Translate - Перемещение.
Rotate - Поворачивание
Подробнее [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/graphics/index.html).

Comment: не-не , именно для чего нужны fillBefore — когда установлен в true, то преобразование анимации применяется перед началом анимации; fillAfter — когда установлен в true, то преобразование применяется после конца анимации;   В этих видах анимаций -  alpha, scale, translate, rotate и set. Что значит преобразование анимации, до или после?

Comment: Легче ссылку дать. Смысл у них немного не понятен сразу, но вот хорошая статься с примерами, которая позволит на примере визуально понять различие и что это такое http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1203